# How to monitor servers using SMPP + Nagios/Centreon?

Tags: prometheus, nagios

The scenario I have is a system that transmits information about the servers over SMPP. Since SMPP being known for being an SMS protocol, the server information is inside the SMS content in JSON format. This data is currently being parsed added to Prometheus.

In my little project at the moment the data from Prometheus is displayed in Grafana and if I want to keep tabs on alerts I need to keep on watching it all day long.

My question is, how can I have Nagios implemented (if applicable)? I believe I could be consuming the data from Prometheus and working the alert administration in Nagios/Centreon for example (or maybe Prometheus alert manager), and this way no one would ever have to be staring at the statuses on Grafana.

Is it possible? Or what is the best way to have those alerts handled?

I am pretty new in the topic and never really implemented or used such software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nagios works by running "checks" on a schedule and alerting you when the output is not what you expect. Every "check" uses a "plugin", which could be a shell script, a binary file, or anything that gives back a result in a way that Nagios expects.

If you're able to get to the JSON via HTTP, you could probably set up a Nagios installation with a host and a service, where the service uses a check command that uses a plugin like [`check_json`](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/Others/check_json/details).

Nagios is a bit tricky if you've never used it before, but it's definitely possible. I haven't used Prometheus alert manager myself so I can't speak for it, but if Prometheus is already consuming the data, it seems like a way easier solution to just set up an alert in Prometheus than doing it with a completely separate piece of software (Nagios).